# Is there a way to generate HTML using PHP for validation purposes?

Tags: php, html, validation

What I mean by this is, is I have organized modules and I want to run the PHP output through a w3 validator.  Bascially what you would see in a `view source` if you were on the page.

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php include 'module._TopHead.htm';?>
  <body>
    <?php include 'module._TopBody.htm';?>
    <script>
      <?php include 'object-inline.ArcInit.js';?>
      <?php include 'object-inline.FBInit.js';?>
    </script>
    <div id="super-1">
    </div>
    <div id="mega_wrap">
      <div id="ultra-1">
```

In fact I could just copy paste the view source, but I was hoping there was a programmatic way to do this.

Also, this would speed up server response if I could save the file as `foo.htm` and call it directly.

Comment: You could use the Unix utilities `wget` and `curl` (assuming the validate is hosted on a w3c server), both those utilities could be used via PHP but bash might be simpler. Let me know if you'd be interested in a fleshed out answer. Do you have a complete sitemap available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function version with some configuration options for OSX.

```
#!/bin/sh

#OSX configuration
alias md5sum='md5 -r'
alias browser='open -a Safari'

#temp directory
wd=~/root/web/sites

#build directory
bd=~/root/web/source/build

makeHTM () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo >&2 "No URL given"
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <URL>"
        exit
    fi
    download_path="/$bd/monster.htm"
    validated_path="/$wd/monster_validated.htm"
    curl -kL $1 > $download_path
    curl -F upload_file=@$download_path https://validator.w3.org/nu/ > \
    $validated_path
    browser $validated_path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script for exactly this purpsoe. It's a shell script. You need to call the script with a URL, the URL can also be a local website.
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Written by Stefan Völkl

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo >&2 "No URL given"
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <URL>"
    exit
fi

# converting the url to a md5 sum
url_md5=`echo $1 | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1`

# setting paths
download_path="/tmp/${url_md5}.html"
validated_path="/tmp/${url_md5}_validated.html"

# saving the site via curl
curl -kL $1 > $download_path

# upload of a site via curl to the w3c validator and writing the output into a
# file
curl -F upload_file=@$download_path https://validator.w3.org/nu/ > \
$validated_path

# output result in x-www-browser
x-www-browser $validated_path
```

Comment: For some reason my bash shell does not recognize md5sum

Comment: You could remove the part with de md5sum and generate a random name for the file. md5sum just seemed perfect to me for having individual file names while up- and downloading hundreds of files.